# How to deal with itertools.product when using numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, python-itertools

I want to get tensor products of two numpy arrays. For example, given

```
a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=[10,2])
b = np.random.uniform(2,3,size=[20,3])
```

and I want to take

```
products = np.array(list(prod for prod in itertools.product(a,b)))
```

However, when I do this, the resulting array will be

```
[[array([-0.0954691 ,  0.36734629])
  array([2.20196909, 2.02029329, 2.29627849])]
  ...
 [array([-0.07571476,  0.95934329])
  array([2.46847944, 2.3456241 , 2.28091522])]]
```

I want to get rid of 'array' in the list to get

```
 [[[-0.0954691 ,  0.36734629],[2.20196909, 2.02029329, 2.29627849]]
  ...
  [[-0.07571476,  0.95934329],[2.46847944, 2.3456241 , 2.28091522]]]
```

Possibly I can use

```
for i in range(products.shape[0]):
    np.concatenate((products[i][0], products[i][1]))
```

But I think there is more clever way to do it.
Can anyone help me?Thanks.

Comment: The product is producing combinations of the rows of the arrays. The rows themselves are arrays. Since some have 2 elements and others 3, the result is an object dtype array containing arrays. Nested arrays rather than nested lists.  The word 'array' tells us what they are.  It's not superfluous decoration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve it with one for loop instead of two

```
a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=[1,2])
b = np.random.uniform(2,3,size=[1,3])

temp_array = []
result_array=[]
for prod in itertools.product(a,b):
    temp_array.append(list(prod[0]))
    temp_array.append(list(prod[1]))
    result_array.append(temp_array)
    temp_array=[]
```

**Answer is  result_array**

```
> [[[0.5345439210605363, -0.3895013480686571],   [2.6760262824054353, > 2.1221940892354487, 2.4009406883314517]], 
 [[0.5345439210605363, -0.3895013480686571],   [2.367796128612561, 2.1553525177821724, 2.638708096912526]],
...
...
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [129]: products = np.array(list(prod for prod in itertools.product(a,b)))
```

The result is a 2d array - but with object dtype:

```
In [130]: products.shape                                                        
Out[130]: (200, 2)
```

The first row of this array, is also object dtype, with 2 elements, each an array:

```
In [131]: products[0]                                                           
Out[131]: 
array([array([-0.38279696,  0.51916671]),
       array([2.26576386, 2.50428761, 2.1463347 ])], dtype=object)
```

It contains the first rows of `a` and `b`:

```
In [132]: a[0]                                                                  
Out[132]: array([-0.38279696,  0.51916671])
In [133]: b[0]                                                                  
Out[133]: array([2.26576386, 2.50428761, 2.1463347 ])
```

Since those arrays have different lengths, the resulting combination must be object dtype.  If `a` and `b` had the same number of columns, you'd get numeric array

For example with `a` and `a`:

```
In [134]: arr = np.array(list(prod for prod in itertools.product(a,a)))         
In [135]: arr.shape                                                             
Out[135]: (100, 2, 2)
In [136]: arr.dtype                                                             
Out[136]: dtype('float64')
```

If we convert `a` and `b` to lists (nested), we again get a 2d object array - containing lists:

```
In [137]: products = np.array(list(prod for prod in itertools.product(a.tolist()
     ...: ,b.tolist())))                                                        
In [138]: products.shape                                                        
Out[138]: (200, 2)
In [139]: products[0,:]                                                         
Out[139]: 
array([list([-0.38279696426849363, 0.5191667144605163]),
       list([2.2657638604936015, 2.50428761464766, 2.1463346999537767])],
      dtype=object)
```

If we omit the `array` wrapper, we get a list of tuples (of lists):

```
In [140]: products = list(prod for prod in itertools.product(a.tolist(),b.tolist
     ...: ()))                                                                  
In [141]: len(products)                                                         
Out[141]: 200
In [142]: products[0]                                                           
Out[142]: 
([-0.38279696426849363, 0.5191667144605163],
 [2.2657638604936015, 2.50428761464766, 2.1463346999537767])
In [143]: type(products)                                                        
Out[143]: list
```

`product` produces tuples (see its docs), as seen in this simpler example:

```
In [145]: list(itertools.product('abc','def'))                                  
Out[145]: 
[('a', 'd'),
 ('a', 'e'),
 ('a', 'f'),
 ('b', 'd'),
 ('b', 'e'),
 ('b', 'f'),
 ('c', 'd'),
 ('c', 'e'),
 ('c', 'f')]
```

## edit

Splitting the `prod` tuple as you comment:

```
In [147]: arr0 = np.array(list(prod[0] for prod in itertools.product(a,b)))     
In [148]: arr1 = np.array(list(prod[1] for prod in itertools.product(a,b)))     
In [149]: arr0.shape                                                            
Out[149]: (200, 2)
In [150]: arr1.shape                                                            
Out[150]: (200, 3)
In [151]: arr0[:3,:]                                                            
Out[151]: 
array([[-0.38279696,  0.51916671],
       [-0.38279696,  0.51916671],
       [-0.38279696,  0.51916671]])
In [152]: arr1[:3,:]                                                            
Out[152]: 
array([[2.26576386, 2.50428761, 2.1463347 ],
       [2.63018066, 2.64559639, 2.51747175],
       [2.14425882, 2.39274225, 2.6460254 ]])
```

These are two numeric arrays.

They could be joined on axis=1 to make an array with 5 columns:

```
In [153]: arr3 = np.hstack((arr0,arr1))                                         
In [154]: arr3[:3,:]                                                            
Out[154]: 
array([[-0.38279696,  0.51916671,  2.26576386,  2.50428761,  2.1463347 ],
       [-0.38279696,  0.51916671,  2.63018066,  2.64559639,  2.51747175],
       [-0.38279696,  0.51916671,  2.14425882,  2.39274225,  2.6460254 ]])
```

## bonus

Making a structured array from these 2 arrays:

```
In [159]: dt=np.dtype([('a',float,2),('b',float,3)])                            
In [160]: arr3 = np.zeros(200,dt)                                               
In [161]: arr3['a']=arr0                                                        
In [162]: arr3['b']=arr1                                                        
In [163]: arr3[:3]                                                              
Out[163]: 
array([([-0.38279696,  0.51916671], [2.26576386, 2.50428761, 2.1463347 ]),
       ([-0.38279696,  0.51916671], [2.63018066, 2.64559639, 2.51747175]),
       ([-0.38279696,  0.51916671], [2.14425882, 2.39274225, 2.6460254 ])],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8', (2,)), ('b', '<f8', (3,))])
```

Comment: Oh, this is a perfect explaination what I want to know! So, I should separate thinks like 
```
arr0 = np.array(list(prod[0] for prod in itertools.product(a,b)))   
arr1 = np.array(list(prod[1] for prod in itertools.product(a,b)))   
```
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try nested for loops that convert each array into a list:

```
import numpy as np 
import itertools

a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=[10,2])
b = np.random.uniform(2,3,size=[20,3])

products = np.array(list(prod for prod in itertools.product(a,b)))
print(products)

products = [list(i) for product in products for i in product]
print(products)
```

**Example:**

```
a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,size=[1,2])
b = np.random.uniform(2,3,size=[1,3])
```

**Output of example:**

```
# This is the first print output
[[array([-0.76844481, -0.77955549])
  array([ 2.73748408,  2.65023585,  2.49984462])]] 

# This is the second print output
[[-0.76844480922803649, -0.77955548831103427], [2.7374840778087144, 2.6502358496635754, 2.4998446233196443]]
```

Comment: This will return arrays like [prod[0][0], prod[0][1], prod[1][0], prod[1][1], ...] but I want [[prod[0][0], prod[0][1]], [prod[1][0], prod[1][1]], ...].

Comment: From what I can see this does return how you mentioned - aka a list of lists. Not sure if you checked it out, see my toy example above.